# Using model for ID assignment

Tags: sapui5

I tried to assign ID to items in my select control using model binding, but ended with an error.

Here is my code:

**Model:**

```
{
    "languages": [
        {
        "language": "English",
        "locale": "en"
        }, 
        {
        "language": "German",
        "locale": "de"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Select control:**

```
var oLanguageSelection = new sap.m.Select({
            name:   'languageSelection',
            id:     'languageSelection',
            items: { 
                path: "languages>/languages",
                template: new sap.ui.core.Item({
                    id: "{languages>locale}", //this is the problematic part
                    text: "{languages>language}",
                }),

            },
});
```

**Error I get:**

```
Uncaught Error: "{languages>locale}" is not a valid ID.
```

Is it possible at all to do what I am trying to do - assign element ID using model binding?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think id is not bindable. ID refers to the control id that is also used in the DOM. What you are trying to do should be achieved with the [key](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Item.html#constructor) property :)

```
var oLanguageSelection = new sap.m.Select({
    name:   'languageSelection',
    id:     'languageSelection',
    selectedKey: "{languages>/languages/0/locale}", // you might want to set a default selection
    items: { 
        path: "languages>/languages",
        template: new sap.ui.core.Item({
            key: "{languages>locale}", // no longer problematic ;)
            text: "{languages>language}"
        })  
    }
});
```

Comment: How do i incorporate this in XML view @cschuff