# SAPUI5 Access json model from another controller

Tags: json, xml, sapui5

i am new to SAPUI5 and im doing some exercises about Master and Detail pages.

I have 2 views, **Master.view.xml** and **Detail.view.xml**.
The **Master.view.xml** contains a list of employees. When the user clicks on an employee, it will navigate to the detail view. The **Detail.view.xml** contains the detail of the selected employee.

Each view has its corresponding controller.
I've put my json model in the **Master.controller.js**.

How can i access the json model from the **Master.controller.js** to the **Detail.view.xml** without passing the data? Is this even possible?

---

@keshet

This is the List i have created in the Master page:

```
<List  xmlns="sap.m"
            id="masterList"
                headerText="{i18n>masterHeaderText}"
                footerText="Updated: September 4, 2015"
                items="{/employeeDetails}"
                itemPress="" >
                    <StandardListItem xmlns="sap.m" 
                        id="{empid}"
                        title="{name}"
                        description="{levelDesc}"
                        info="{cubeNo}"
                        type="Navigation"
                        tap="handleListItemPress"  />
            </List>
```

Now i am trying to change the id of the StandardListItem to the ID of the employee that is from the model. But an error appears saying i cant use the **empid** as id of the StandardListItem. How do i do this?

Comment: Take a look at this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27274452/using-model-for-id-assignment)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can declare your model globally, so all views will have access to it.
To define global model:

```js
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oData);
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);
```

To retrieve the data from the model in another view:

```js
var oData = sap.ui.getCore().getModel().getData();
```

You also can give a name to your model if you want to use several global models:

```js
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oData);
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel, "modelname");

var oData = sap.ui.getCore().getModel("modelname").getData();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @keshet. I did this but i cant test it yet on the detail page. I am still working on passing the ID of the selected list from the Master page to the Detail page.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting your model to master. Now in detail get the view and it's corresponding model.

Master Controller-

> oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oData);
>   sap.ui.getView().setModel(oModel);

Detail or anywhere you want:-

> oModel = sap.ui.getView().getModel();