# SAPUI5 routing : Is it possible to pass models between views / controllers?

Tags: sapui5

I have 2 separate views, each with their own controller.

First view is the first "Part" of a survey, second view is the rest.

I have a model view setup for each, but is is possible to pass the details of the First page's model to use in the second?

I know you can include parameters in routing but they're large text fields in this case.

The other option I have is to save the details in the back-end and only pass over a reference number of the created model as a parameter.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SAPUI5 Access json model from another controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32492192/sapui5-access-json-model-from-another-controller)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to put your First page's model in the method `init` of [`Component.js`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/27ce0e4987cd426f8fa3e60836316428).

If you want to access the model, in your second View [`Controller`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller) , you can call `getOwnerComponent` of to access the Component and the First page's model.

Hope it helps.