# binding data to id of control sap ui5

Tags: data-binding, sapui5

I am working at binding control using SAP UI5 with object model.

```
<layout:VerticalLayout content="{oModel>/part2/chartContents}" width="100%">
                                    <layout:fixContent>
                                        <viz:VizFrame id="{oModel>id}" uiConfig="{applicationSet:'fiori'}" vizType='column' >
                                            <viz:dataset>
                                                <viz.data:FlattenedDataset data="{oModel>data/milk}">
                                                    <viz.data:dimensions>
                                                        <viz.data:DimensionDefinition name="Week" value="{oModel>Week}" />
                                                    </viz.data:dimensions>
                                                    <viz.data:measures>
                                                        <viz.data:MeasureDefinition name="Revenue" value="{oModel>Revenue}" />
                                                        <viz.data:MeasureDefinition name="Cost" value="{oModel>Cost}" />
                                                    </viz.data:measures>
                                                </viz.data:FlattenedDataset>
                                            </viz:dataset>
                                            <viz:feeds>
                                                <viz.feeds:FeedItem id='valueAxisFeed' uid="valueAxis" type="Measure" values="Revenue" />
                                                <viz.feeds:FeedItem id='categoryAxisFeed' uid="categoryAxis" type="Dimension" values="Week" />
                                            </viz:feeds>
                                        </viz:VizFrame>
                                    </layout:fixContent>
                                </layout:FixFlex>
                            </layout:VerticalLayout>
```

**My data model:**

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JOSNModel({part2: {chartContents: [{
                            title: "a. tile 1",
                            linkText: "detail",
                            id: "idoChart1
                            metaData: {
                                reportName: "first Report",
                                from: "",
                                to: ""
                            },
                            data: {
                                "milk": [{
                                        "Week": "Week 1 - 4",
                                        "Revenue": 431000.22,
                                        "Cost": 230000,
                                        "Cost1": 24800.63,
                                        "Cost2": 205199.37,
                                        "Target": 500000,
                                        "Budget": 210000
                                    }]
                                   }
           }]}})
this.getView().setModel(oModel, "oModel");
```

But in property `id="{oModel>id}"`, it does not work, although other properties have the correct value.

**Question**

How can I bind value (ID) in the object model to control of SAP UI5?

Comment: "it does not work" is not the way to describe a problem if you want useful help.

Comment: Id is not a bindable property. You could use a custom data field - which is bindable - to identify sub-controls later.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using model for ID assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27274452/using-model-for-id-assignment)

Comment: `id` is **not** bindable since it's one of the *specialSettings* [(src)](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject#specialsettings). It's not a ManagedObject *property*. Only ManagedObject properties and aggregations are bindable in UI5.

Answer (score -1):

```
id="{oModel>/id}"
```

Comment: Good answers should come with explanations. Please explain what the extra / is for.

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Comment: This answer is plain wrong. `id` is **not** bindable since it's one of the *specialSettings* [(src)](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject#specialsettings). It's not a ManagedObject *property*. Only ManagedObject properties and aggregations are bindable in UI5. Please try the solution before answering.